# file_get_contents http error bots blocked by webserver

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
file_get_contents("http://capes.labymod.net/capes/e4314058-987e-41ee-93b0-33bebfe726a0",false,$context);

?>
```

Doesn't work. `capes.labymod.net` are blocking bots. Can PHP fix that problem?

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184869/how-to-disguise-your-php-script-as-a-browser

Comment: Please describe exactly what is your problem and what you want to do.